# Can a rest api be IP address? or must it be a url?

Tags: node.js, rest, restful-url

I am debugging a problem right now at work, and wondering if rest api can be ip address or must it be a url (ie. www.google.com/countries)

Comment: It can be, but not all are.  It all depends on the configuration of the Server and the API itself.

Answer (score 1):

> I am debugging a problem right now at work, and wondering if rest api can be ip address or must it be a url (ie. [www.google.com/countries](http://www.google.com/countries))

TL;DR: yes, it can be an IP address.

Typically, REST uses uniform resource identifiers, which are described by [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986).  You seem to be asking specifically about the host portion, described in [section 3.2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.2.2).

> The host subcomponent of authority is identified by an IP literal encapsulated within square brackets, an IPv4 address in dotted-decimal form, or a registered name.

The standards for dealing with IPv6 zone identifiers is described by [RFC 6874](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6874).